# JPS error in hadoop

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I have installed java and hadoop in my ubuntu-12.10. While installing hadoop I had created a hadoop group. When I run jps command inside hadoop it says I have to install jdk whereas when I run jps outside hadoop it is working fine. I have set the PATH to include java in both etc/environment and etc/profile. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might have created separate user for hadoop installation and might have installed java on your admin(or any other) user.

Solution is :
run this command: "$JAVA_HOME/bin/jps" in hadoop user

here $JAVA_HOME is the location where u installed jvm(java)